# How to to pass a string to function arguments in python3

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm building a command-line interface using the argparse library to parse user input. At one stage, I'd like to take user input such as `"'test', x=False"` and use it in a function such as `func('test', x=False)`.

I've tried using ast.literal_eval to do this but it encounters a syntax error at the equals sign. (I did `ast.literal_eval("("+args+")")` where `args` was above example)

Does anyone know of a safe way to parse the user input like that? Preferably without eval although worst-case scenario I could use eval as, well, it's a CLI tool.

Edit (to people that have said to use input manually(): I need the tool to parse input from when the command is run (it's a python module that I want to be able to be called like `python3 -m hmcli.raw --args "'test', x=False"` where the `args` can be flexible as the function used can differ.

Comment: Why not take the input as 2 separate inputs and call it with the variables? `first = input()`, `x = input()`, `func(first, x)` ?

Comment: An `argparse` parser normally parses `sys.argv[1:]`, the list provided by the system from the script command line.  It can also parse a list provided by you.  Experiment with `args=parser.parse_args(input().split())`.

Comment: @AK47 i need to parse from the command given. Updated the post to explain.

Comment: @hpaulj the issue isn't with argparse collecting arguments, it's with some how getting `"'test', x=False"` into something that i can pass into a function that accepts `y, x=True`

Comment: `shlex` will split a string in the same way a shell would, giving better handling of quotes than the simplistic `.split()`.

Comment: If you are focused on parsing 'x=False' why did you tag this as `argparse`?  That's not the kind of input `argparse` handles.

Comment: There have been other SO questions on handling general 'key=value' inputs.  Basically the parsing is up to you, eg split on '=' and make a dictionary.

Comment: @hpaulj once I have the dictionary, how would I pass it to a function (like `dict1 = {'key':'value'}` to `func1(key='value')`)?

Comment: `func1(**dict1)`